# How to sort and display posts by selected category

Tags: wordpress, sorting, filter, posts

I'm having a Wordpress blog system on cars. On my home page in a one div I display most recent 5 posts.

Now I want to filter these posts by user selected post category.

There is a drop down with my posts categories and user can select a category from there. Once a user select a category from there I need to show the posts which are related to that category only, without refreshing the page.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Dropdown change , pass the current selected category id in the url as parameter like : www.abc.com/currentpageurl?catid=3
get the id  value from url using php i.e $_GET['catid'],  and simply use cat option in your wp query which will gives you specific category post

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps.

1. On form submit you have to create an ajax request (you can do it with jQuery), this ajax request should return your filtered posts and after that you can replace your old posts with the filtered ones using `.html()` method as an option.
2. Create the function in your current WP theme `functions.php`, that is connected to `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` action hooks. This function will receive your category ID as a `$_POST` parameter and will use it in `WP_Query` to regenerate filtered posts.

I know it is better to share the code with you, so you can find a good example here https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html

Comment: how to do that without using a button and on dropdown select action

Comment: Just replace `$('#filter').submit(function(){` method with `$('select').change(function(){` method.

Comment: Then again where should i use  jQuery-based processing code in admin-ajax.php file? beginning or end of the existing code? thanks.

Comment: jQuery-processing code (I suppose you mean that PHP function) is for your current theme functions.php file

Comment: no i meant the jquery part you have described on your tutorial, (Step 2. jQuery script to Send a Request and to Receive Result Data) where should i place that code?

Comment: Ok, I see. The jQuery part you can insert in any .js file that is included in your HTML code after the jquery.js itself or just in your HTML between <script> tags.

Comment: so in this case i should place it on admin-ajax.php file correct?

Comment: You should never touch admin-ajax.php file :) jQuery is in your custom js file (or inside your HTML template), PHP - in your theme functions.php file, that's all.

Comment: i inserted that jquery into my functions.php, but it gives me an error..

Comment: Everything is described in the comment above and in tutorial. If you got an error, you've inserted something in a wrong place

Comment: I just copy pasted you jqurey in my functions.php, changed nothing..?